# Improving code for a jQuery Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting with JS ans jQuery and I've been trying to improve the code for a Bootstrap 3 button I'm working on.

It has two inside spans, one with the text and one with the chevrons font icons.

I was wondering if there was a way to optimize my code (just for the sake of learning).

Here is my working code.

First the HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-imgs">
 <span class="btn-imgs-toggle">Ocultar Imágenes </span>                                      
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> 
</button>
```

now the jQuery:

```
$('.btn-imgs').click(function(){
    $('.thumbnail img').toggle();

    //variables
    var icono = $(this).children('.glyphicon');

    var $text = $(this).children('.btn-imgs-toggle');

    //cambia texto del boton
    $text.toggleClass('mostrar');

    //si el texto y el icono coinciden con un tipo cambialos al otro
    if( $text.hasClass('mostrar') && $(icono).is('.glyphicon-chevron-up')){
        $text.text('Mostrar imágenes');
        $(icono).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    } 

    else {
        $text.text('Ocultar imágenes');
        $(icono).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    }



});
```

Thanks a lot for any inputs on this. I've been learning quite a lot searching through other posted questions.

Comment: If you would like help optimizing code which is functioning correctly, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! didin't know about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I don't think there is any reason to do a double check on the state of the children, unless you have other scripts that will modify these elements. Also, `icono` is already a jQuery object when you define it, there is no reason to wrap it with the jQuery method.

If I were writing this, I would approach it this way:

```
$(body).on('click', '.btn-imgs', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.thumbnail img').toggle(); // how are you sure you are toggling the correct state?
    // I would consider including this in the conditional, but I don't know the purpose of
    // this, so I will leave it as is.
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up')
    .siblings('.btn-imgs-toggle').toggleClasS('mostrar').text(function () {
        return ($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-chevron-down') ? 'Mostrar' : 'Ocultar') + ' imágenes';
    });
});
```